# use AVAudioEngine for video's playback

Tags: macos, audio, video, avfoundation, avaudioengine

I'm new to Swift and OSX, so apologies if this is a silly question.
I'm trying to create a video player that will allow the user to pitch-shift (i.e. change the audio frequency) the soundtrack of a video whilst it's playing , using a slider.

I've figured out how to do this for audio using AVAudioEngine (based on this tutorial https://www.robotlovesyou.com/mixing-between-effects-with-avfoundation/ ) and I've also figured out how to playback video.

However, I'm stuck on applying AvAudioEngine to the audio of a video track (I'm trying .mp4, but I'd like this to work in any format).

Is there a way to do this? Or if not, is there another way to achieve my real goal of pitch shifting the audio soundtrack in realtime (whilst the video is playing)?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, not yet - I've been diverted onto other things - will let you know if/when I do figure it out